# Drupal 7 Views PHP (views_php) module error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pantheon

Views PHP module give following error in site audit report:

> **Unfinished and incomplete**, Views PHP permits executable code to be stored in the database with no revisioning; a typo introduced in the Views UI can bring down an entire production site with no accountability. See http://api.drupal.org/api/views for details on how to implement your own custom Views functionality.

How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bug in some of installed modules. Are you maybe using something called "Pantheon"?

https://www.drupal.org/node/2420591

Anyway, try turning off some modules and see will error still appear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...yes we are using pantheon hosting for drupal.Is there any other solution then disable other module because all module which is install and enabled are used for some functionality.Any particular module which caused this issue??